# Random computer luggishness using Blender

Tags: force-fields, mouse

I am following some littlwebhut tutorials and things are going OK, until my computer slows way down and won't do what the video tutorial is doing.
I could not get it to apply a forcefield last night, today that seemed to work but now it does not want to move a selected object and the mouse takes off up the screen without my moving it. ESC key seems to stop the mouse running but I still cannot get the text to move.
......
Opening Task Manager shows an increase in CPU usage but I don't know how to see the history, so I can't tell if it is only up because I opened Task Manager or if it was up for another reason, when it opened it dropped off very quickly, so maybe it was just the effort of opening Task Manager.
.............
I ran an MalwareBytes scan and an Avast virus scan, I found nothing.
I don't have a bunch of cracked software on my box, so I don't think there is some random script running. 
I don't get it.
..........
Anyway, here is my rig. In case there are known errors or I don't have enough horsepower, or whatever.

```
Tech Support Guy System Info Utility version 1.0.0.2
OS Version: Microsoft Windows 10 Home, 64 bit
Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor, AMD64 Family 21 Model 2 Stepping 0
Processor Count: 8
RAM: 16330 Mb
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, -1 Mb
Hard Drives: C: Total - 487526 MB, Free - 35992 MB; D: Total - 1430346 MB, Free - 1012515 MB; F: Total - 1907726 MB, Free - 950081 MB; G: Total - 7630755 MB, Free - 3912544 MB; P: Total - 3815412 MB, Free - 165786 MB;
Motherboard: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC., M5A97
Antivirus: Avast Antivirus, Updated and Enabled
```

Thanks for taking time to look at this question

Comment: Overheating causes your computer to become sluggish. If you are using laptop, it is overheating with EMF radiation. Your laptop is heating like a microwave oven, unless you have something to absorb EMF. Try  product DefenderShield pad which you slip under your laptop. It is as effective as heatsink. It absorbs EMF, thus cooling your laptop and making less whirling noise.  https://youtu.be/-ABzbqKCrd0

Answer (score 0):

This may be a amazing solution but I would recommend uploading important files to google drive or something of that nature then resetting pc. I have had issues like this in the past with different programs and it can happen because of lots of extra stuff running that is extra stuff that you never use. I have had this happen before and resetting it, it was like insane. Hope this helped!!